# How to configure Nant plugin in Jenkins

Tags: nant, jenkins-plugins

I have Jenkins with Nant-plugin. I have one job with nunit tests. When building the project I get an error:

> Executing command: cmd.exe /C ""NAnt.exe ./nant.build && exit
>   %%ERRORLEVEL%%"" [GuiTests] $ cmd.exe /C '"NAnt.exe ./nant.build &&
>   exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%"' 'NAnt.exe' is not recognized as an internal or
>   external command, operable program or batch file.

Does it mean that I should install nant and manually set up environment variable? So why Nant-plugin?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, like ANT plugin it requires an external installation. You can configure an automatic installation on the main Jenkins configuration page (`http://<jenkins-server>/configure`, search for *Nant Builder*), but in my experience it is better not to get involved with Jenkins automatic installations - they are rather quirky.

The reason for the plugin is portability of your builds. With the plugin you do not have to specify different build steps for, say, your Linux (*Execute Shell*) and Windows (*Execute Windows batch command*) builds, but rather can use the same *Execute NAnt build* step.